# Alternative way of refreshing datagrid other than timer.tick()

Tags: c#, timer, datagrid, backgroundworker

I have two solutions. 1 for the datagrid view ( for display purposes only) and one for the input.

Is there a alternative way of refreshing datagrid every second? or if not every second. Is there anything I can use?

I've read about backgroundwoker

, but it also needs to fire the backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();

Comment: Can you add your code to your question?

Comment: _"Is there anything I can use?"_ -- yes, of course there is. The modern C# idiom is to run a look in an `async` method where you `await Task.Delay(...)` the interval you want to wait between refreshes. But there are already lots of answers on Stack Overflow explaining this. See marked duplicates for some options on executing code periodically with `Task.Delay()`.